# Mura 6 and jquery validations 1.13.1 - Invalid form gets submitted

Tags: jquery-validate, coldfusion-10, mura

I am using jquery 1.8.3 and jquery validation plugin 1.13.1 which is a latest validation version. my form looks like this,

```
<form method="post" class="contact-form" id="frmB5B976FFD59E885191DA4D572F6F773A" action="?nocache=1#frmB5B976FFD59E885191DA4D572F6F773A" novalidate="novalidate"><input type="hidden" value="true" name="useProtect">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" class="cffp_mm" name="formfield1234567891" id="fp6939F8D3-F46A-C008-37330D6AA1B0BED2">
  <input type="hidden" value="" class="cffp_kp" name="formfield1234567892" id="fp6939F8D4-FE37-FF6D-AD27DC356205A886">
  <input type="hidden" value="39890522,19894825" name="formfield1234567893" id="fp6939F8D6-F82F-92B8-A4B0BA6A966190FA">
  <label style="display:none">Leave this field empty <input type="text" value="" name="formfield1234567894" id="fp6939F8D7-AB86-5202-464CA191E50CE678"></label>
  <p class="column one-half"><input type="text" required="" placeholder="Please Enter First Name" name="fname" id="fname" aria-required="true"></p>
  <p class="column one-half last"><input type="text" required="" placeholder="Please Enter Last Name" name="lname" aria-required="true"></p>
  <p class="column one-half"><input type="email" required="" placeholder="Please Enter Email" name="email" aria-required="true"></p>
  <p class="column one-half last"><input type="text" required="" placeholder="Please Enter Phone Number" name="tel" aria-required="true"></p>
  <p class="clear"><textarea rows="3" required="" placeholder="Please Enter Message" name="comment" cols="5" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" id="submitme" value="Submit" name="submitme"></p>
</form>
```

And my validations looks like this -

```
 var ruleSet = {required: true};
 jQuery( "#frmB5B976FFD59E885191DA4D572F6F773A" ).validate({
  rules:{
        fname: ruleSet,
        lname: ruleSet,
        email: { required: true, email: true },
        phone: { required: true, phoneUS: true },
        message: { required: true }
  }
});
```

The form is in forms section in mura admin. I created that using form editor. I am unable to understand why the form gets submitted even when there are invalid fields, Could it be because HTML5 validations are turned off by validation plugin and Mura just submits the form no matter if the form is valid or invalid! But then why doesn't the validation plugin do `preventdefault()` if the validations fails? 
Also, I tried using JSFiddle for the validations and it works there. Please help me out. Thanks.
FYI. The above form html is the one from "page source" and not actual form from the form editor. That is why all the weird `form id` and `cffp_mm` etc.

Comment: JavaScript does not care about your framework or CMS.  All that matters is the code rendered in the browser source.   Meanwhile, the code you've shown us is working perfectly fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/oemuca7u/

Comment: If the form is submitting while invalid, it simply means that something is broken within the JavaScript.  Look at your browser's JavaScript error console.

Comment: I do not get any error in `firebug`. I did mention in my question that the code works fine in fiddle. I debugged more and found out that Mura calls a function `validate()` which is an ajax call once the submit button is clicked. URL was this `localhost/tasks/validate/remote.cfc?method=validate`

Comment: You also have rules defined by `phone` and `message` but the `name` on those fields are `tel` and `comment`.  You must declare rules using the correct `name` attributes.

Comment: `localhost/tasks/validate/remote.cfc?method=validate` has absolutely nothing to do with JavaScript or jQuery Validate's `.validate()` method.

Comment: Yup my mistake. I changed the field names now. But submits invalid form.

Comment: If there are no JS errors and the form works in sFiddle and not in your website, then you need to compare the differences between the two pages line by line.

Comment: That `validate` Method was indeed the cause, My primary guess is though jQuery `validate` method puts `novalidate` on the form, it does it late enough to give a chance for mura to proceed with its own validations and hence the form was getting submitted, I had to manually put `novalidate` there. I might be wrong but the below answer did trick. Appreciate  your help :) thanks. Of course it was my fault I posted the rendered html form from page source and not actual one. You might have caught that mistake there itself.

Comment: Actually, since you're posting about JavaScript, the rendered code is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

To those who came here searching for the same issue. I added `novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return true;` to the `form` tag and it did the trick. Mura was overriding the jquery validations, even though jQuery Validation plugin was putting the `novalidate` attribute in form tag, so I had to manually add `novalidate` there. I hope this helps.

Comment: The answer does not make any sense given the content of your OP.   The `novalidate` tag is automatically put there when jQuery Validate is initialized and it's only there to stop HTML5 validation.  Whether it's there or not, jQuery Validate is what's stopping the invalid form from submitting.  Something unidentified is breaking your JavaScript or stopping the plugin from initializing properly.

Comment: Was `onsubmit="return true;` there this whole time?  I can't see how that's going to help anything.  What happens when you remove it?